# in array in big array jQuery not show result but if check like result

Tags: jquery, arrays

```
0: {color: '', size: 'error_check'}
1: {color: '', size: ''}
2: {color: '', size: ''}
```

**in array query not working
this my code**

```
if(jQuery.inArray('error_check', error)) {
   console.log("is in array");
} else {
   console.log("is NOT in array");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want this :

```js
const arr = [ {color: '', size: 'error_check'}, {color: '', size: ''}, {color: '', size: ''}]
if (arr.some(e => e.size === 'error_check')) {
  console.log("is in array");
} else {
   console.log("is NOT in array");
}
```